# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL server and suddenly I am getting this error. Due to that, I am not able to insert data into any table.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction
```

I have checked solution online and found that the `default_transaction_read_only` parameter needs to be set to `off` but it is off already.

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();`? Does the PostgreSQL log file offer any clues?

Comment: Where did you check the value of `default_transaction_read_only`? It can be set globally, at database level or at user level. Does your Java code maybe call `Connection.setReadOnly(true)` at some point? Or some code runs `set transaction read only;`?

Comment: Did you use PGBouncer ? or HikariCP as connection pooler ?

Comment: I had the same error due to a lack of storage space on Azure PG.

Answer (score 3):

Log on to PostgreSQL and verify if your database is in recovery mode or not with below command :-

- **select pg_is_in_recovery();**

> pg_is_in_recovery() should be false(f)

- If the above value is true, intimate admin to move the DB out of recovery mode.

Further check if default transaction is read-only or read-write with below command :-

- **show default_transaction_read_only;**

> default_transaction_read_only must be "off"

- If the value is not off, run the below command
- psql -U *username* -d postgres begin; alter database *dbname* set
  default_transaction_read_only = off; commit; \q

If issue persists after performing the above fix, please check on the connection setting and make sure to use **hostname** rather than host IP in place of jdbcUrl

Comment: Thanks for this! In my case, running `set default_transaction_read_only = off;` worked. Didn't need to run anything from the command line.